# Integration of 1/z over a circle that does not contain 0

Tags: complex-analysis

We know this is 0 by the cauchy integral formula. But i am trying to do this following only the integration of a complex function over a curve. But that leads me to calculate the integral containing sin, cos function in denominator. And this is ridiculuously hard to compute, at least to me.

So is there any near way to compute the integral only using the definition of the integration of a complex funtion along a curve?

Thank you

Comment: You can always multiply the denominator (which should be $\sin\theta+i\cos\theta$) by $\sin\theta-i\cos\theta$ to get $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta = 1$.

Comment: It might be also useful to remember $\cos \theta+ i \sin\theta =e^{i \theta}$.

Comment: Yeah i did that. The integral involving cos, sin functions in the denominator were 'real integrals' with upper limit 2pi and the lower limit 0

Comment: Aren't the integrals of sin and cosine 0 for that domain? Like integral of sine is $-\cos$ and integral of cosine is sine.